# Change a icon, not all

Tags: javascript, jquery

I managed to do everything right, open each element. As you can see in the example below all the icons change together, but as it does to replace only what was clicked?

```
$('.list-prod > li > span').on('click', function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle('slow', function() {
        if($(this).is(':visible')) {
            $('.list-prod > li > span').addClass('collapse');
        } else {
            $('.list-prod > li > span').removeClass('collapse');
        }
    });
});
```

[External link demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bdadev/cC7ke/22/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cC7ke/27/)***

```
$('.list-prod > li > span').on('click', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('expand collapse');
    $(this).next().slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Comment: I think he wants to toggle the class after the animation.

Comment: @bda.awk - Didn't get what you meant.. does this work for you? is there anything else you wanted?

Comment: @Krishna Yes, you solved the whole problem, is now working perfectly. I need to learn English and to use google translator.

Comment: @bda.awk - not a problem. glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Here what you should write

```
$('.list-prod > li > span').on('click', function () {
    $(this).next().slideToggle('slow', function () {
        $(this).prev().toggleClass('collapse');
    });
});
```

since `this` within the callback function refer to the collapsed / visible div